# step.map.PropertyMapStep cannot be cast to step.ByModulating

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to run the following query against the AWS Neptune.

```
g.V(1).project('id', 'type', 'properties') \
      .by(id) \
      .by(label) \
      .by(valueMap().by(unfold()))
```

Calling it via HTTP request raises the following error

```
{
    "requestId": "5eb536e9-017a-db82-9234-db5c556e386f",
    "code": "MalformedQueryException",
    "detailedMessage": "Failed to interpret Gremlin query: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.PropertyMapStep cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ByModulating"
}
```

Using the gremlin-python client

```
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 599: {"requestId":"11f7c020-f2d5-445a-b35a-ee531c31a7e3","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"null:by([[UnfoldStep]])"}
```

How the query should look like? I am exhausted of finding out ways to modify the queries in order to be interpreted by Neptune.

Note that the query executes successfully in Gremlin console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the above query could be rewritten as

```
g.V(1).project('id', 'type', 'properties') \
      .by(id) \
      .by(label) \
      .by(properties().group().by(__.key()).by(__.value()))
```

However I am still confused why the original query does not work.
It would be nice, if someone could explain that to me.

Comment: valueMap().by() was added in TinkerPop 3.4 . Vendors are working to adopt the latest spec I am sure but in the meantime you have a few options on workarounds. I have a few examples here (1) http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#tp34vm and here (2) http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#vmunroll

Comment: @KelvinLawrence okay, seems to make more sense now. Actually the query that I was trying to run was borrowed from you tutorial and I was to lazy to read a few more lines. btw, your tutorial is of very much use. Thank you!